# Sonarqube gradle analyzing project, task not found in root project

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

Analysing project with this command

```
.\gradlew sonarqube \   -Dsonar.host.url=http://my.url \   -Dsonar.login=login --stacktrace
```

Getting this error

> org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task '\' not found in root project 'JavaLint'

And here is my gradle file

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.2"
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
archivesBaseName = 'JavaLint'
version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT' 
mainClassName = 'Main'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.test.Run'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src'
        }
    }
 }

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.11.2'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'
}
```

Stack trace
[image: stacktrace]

I don't understand what am i supposed to do with it.

Comment: What was your intent for the \ in `.\gradlew sonarqube \  `?

Comment: I'm just using windows, adding stack trace for more information

Comment: Your error message seems to relate directly to that `\ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like that in windows Terminal:
.\gradlew sonarqube  -Dsonar.host.url=http://my.url   -Dsonar.login=login --stacktrace

After that ，you will find the project already in the SonarQube server.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I have mentioned my mistake in more layman language below!

Answer (score 16):

It looks like you're using [cmder](https://cmder.net/) (it's so beautiful) which means you're on Windows.  For Windows you'll want to provide the arguments to `gradle` as follows

```
./gradlew sonarqube -D "sonar.projectKey=<your_project_name>" -D "sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" -D "sonar.login=<your_project_token>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the accepted answer by @ka whosyour above,I got my answer too.

Ok let me mention the details of how I was doing for an Android project in Android Studio and what I figured out after my research.

From the command generated by the Sonar Dashbaord, it is

`./gradlew sonarqube \-Dsonar.projectKey=LetsGo \-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \-Dsonar.login=53689e9ceab73b3e8a76007d7953af3e9e2b2052`

But, for Windows machine it should actually be:
`gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.projectKey=LetsGo -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=53689e9ceab73b3e8a76007d7953af3e9e2b2052`

This worked like a charm for me.

Notice the Backwards slashes `\` which are not needed on the windows machine.

Also, `./gradlew` works in mac and `gradlew` on windows

Comment: Also note that when using PowerShell, you need to put the java properties in quotes, e.g. `gradlew sonarqube "-Dsonar.projectKey=LetsGo" "-D..."`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure first the directory contains `gradle.build`.

The command for windows :

```
./gradlew sonarqube -D "sonar.projectKey=your_sonarqube_key" -D "sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" -D "sonar.login=your_sonarqube_token"
```

This has worked for me as expected.